# JTextField: focus next component when textfield is full / autoskip / Auto-Tabbing

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to implement autoskip with JTextField, but don't know what is the best way to do this.

*What is autoskip/Auto-Tabbing? When you reach the defined length limit of a textfield, you are automatically taken to the next field. (like pressing Tab, focus next component) Or what name do you use for this behaviour?*

I tried this:

`JTextField.getDocument.addChangeListener()`: compare length and caret position. 
seems usable, but I can't distinguish typed user input from calls to `JTextField.setText(String)`.

Focus should not be changed when text is changed by gui-refresh.

**What do you think is the best way to implement this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Text Field Auto Tab](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/10/25/size-document-filter/).

> Focus should not be changed when text is changed by gui-refresh.

a) removeListener
b) setText
c) addListener

Edit:

If you don't really like the concept of of needing the ChainDocumentFilter, then get rid of all references to that class. You can replace the provideErrorFeedback() method call with a Toolkit.beep() if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want to [add a](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addKeyListener%28java.awt.event.KeyListener%29) [`KeyListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) to the component instead.  You can still check the length and caret position, but it will only fire when a key is pressed/typed.

Your code may look similar to the following:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (getText().length() >= MAX_LENGTH) {
            // Move the focus
        }
    }
});
```

*Edit in response to comment:*
I might suggest using @camickr's suggestion:

```
private DocumentListener myTabChangeListener;
@Override
public void setText(String text) {
    getDocument().removeDocumentListener(myTabChangeListener);
    super.setText(text);
    getDocument().addDocumentListener(myTabChangeListener);
}
```

Comment: This does not work correctly, because when processing this keyTyped-Event, the document has not been updated yet. I could add "1" to the length, but this would not cover Paste-Actions (CTRL-V), where the length is already correct.

Comment: @Synox, yes that is why I created the class I referenced. As a general rule you should never use KeyListeners. They whereused with old AWT applications that use low level API's. Swing is more advanced and has higher level API's that make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

In your listener create a flag isAPI to distinguish whether it's your code calls setText(). Set the flag to true before setText() call and reset it back after.

When it's true do nothing and move focus in opposite case.